# Highcharts - how to disable empty space around Column chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

Whenever I make a column chart I get empty space on the width, with the tag `svg.highcharts-root` and I don't understand how to disable it. This occupies the whole width of the specified div.
You can see below in the following image :

[image]

I have tried everything, setting the margin to 0 etc.
It would be greatly appreciated if anyone knows how to get rid of that space .

Here is the fiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/boutxbuq/8/

Comment: Set pointPadding and groupPadding to 0. https://jsfiddle.net/boutxbuq/12/

Answer (score 0):

Inline SVG (like the one Highcharts generates) can be styled via CSS. To make the column take all available horizontal space all you need is this:

```
rect.highcharts-plot-background {
  width: 100%;
  x: 0;
}
```